# Cronjob is triggered automatically

Tags: linux, cron, centos, centos6

I have created a cron job, which needs to be triggered at 00:01 on the daily basis. Below are the details:

Cronjob configuration:

```
01 00 * * * root /usr/bin/python /opt/scripts/tune.py -t & >/dev/null &
```

Permissions and location of file:

```
root@localhost:/etc/cron.d# ll /etc/cron.d/database_tuning
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 80 Oct 12 01:04 /etc/cron.d/database_tuning
```

However, this cronjob is not triggered automatically at the specified interval. Now, once I edit this file, and change time to 01:12 AM like (12 01 * * *). then it is triggered automatically successfully. So I confirmed that there is no problem with the script/environment, but I am not able to understand that why cronjob is not triggered at 00:01 AM. What is the best possible to debug this ?

Comment: 01 0 * * * root /usr/bin/python /opt/scripts/tune.py -t & >/dev/null &-----> I believe there should be only one digit in hours entry as numbering starts from 0-23.

Answer (score 0):

As Ali also stated, the hour field must be a value between 0-23, so it won't work if you write 00.

The time and date fields are:

```
      field          allowed values
      -----          --------------
      minute         0-59
      hour           0-23
      day of month   1-31
      month          1-12 (or names, see below)
      day of week    0-7 (0 or 7 is Sunday, or use names)
```

A field may contain an asterisk (*), which always stands for
   "first-last".

Take a look at [crontab manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html).